# How to override static abstract method of base in a subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I have an abstract class with a static function that calls other abstract functions. But when I'm creating a new class and overriding abstract function still the original (abstract) function is running.

I have written an example similar to my problem. Please help.
In the following example, I want to run `do_something()` from `Main` not `Base`.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Base(ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something():
        print('Base')

    @staticmethod
    def print_something():
        Base.do_something()

class Main(Base):
    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        print('Main')

Main.print_something()
```

Output:

```
Base
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Main.print_something` doesn't exist, so it resolves to `Base.print_something`, which *explicitly* calls `Base.do_something`, not `Main.do_something`. You probably want `print_something` to be a class method instead.

```
class Base(ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something():
        print('Base')

    @classmethod
    def print_something(cls):
        cls.do_something()

class Main(Base):
    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        print('Main')

Main.print_something()
```

Now when `Main.print_something` resolves to `Base.print_something`, it will still receive `Main` (not `Base`) as its argument, allowing it to invoke `Main.do_something` as desired.